# Batch convert videos from MPG to AVI

Tags: batch, avi, mpg, video-conversion

I have a few hundred short MPEG files (each ~10 seconds) that I need to batch convert to AVI. What would be the best way to do this?

I've tried using WinFF but the quality was very subpar.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: WinFF uses FFMPEG.  Pretty much what most other general conversion tools use. You just need to specify the setting you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SUPER © (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer)](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) can do it. One of its features is multiple batch file processing by simple file drag and drop, and it's freeware.

[Direct download link](http://www.erightsoft.info/GetFile.php?SUPERsetup.exe)

Comment: They need to make downloading that software from that site a little easier, its a treasure hunt to find the link...direct download here...http://www.erightsoft.biz/GetFile.php?SUPERsetup.exe

Comment: @Moab: Free but tiring to download :) Thanks for the link by the way.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't complain about free software. :-)

Answer (score 7):

With [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), which will not re-encode the videos in any way and therefore preserve quality:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -c:v copy -c:a copy file.avi
```

In a batch file, e.g. for Linux:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v copy -c:a copy ${file%%.mpg}.avi
done < <(find . -iname '*.mpg' -print0)
```

In a batch file, e.g. for Windows:

```
for /r %%i in (*.mpg) do (
ffmpeg -i %%i -c:v copy -c:a copy %%i~n.avi
)
```

The last example requires the [Windows build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/).

Comment: +1 for ffmpeg. I've heard rather scary stories about Super wanting to modify files in the `Windows\System32` folder so I avoid it like the plague. Plus if you want to use batch, then command line applications is the way to go.

Comment: +1 Yeh, from personal experience Super acts rather suspicious and takes an insane amount of time to load just for a winforms application. Not sure what it does in background to justify this but it doesn't do anything with videos which can't be achieved with open-source solutions IMAO

Comment: I use ffmpeg too, but... I still don't understand why people who created it didn't released some productive official GUI. Many GUI programs with ffmpeg are full of adware, malware etc. I don't know which is safe to use, and which will infect my computer with SweetPacks or other crap.

Comment: @Kamil The developers have enough to do already, and are continuously improving the tool. Adding a GUI would be a massive overhead, and would probably require a second project of almost the same scale of FFmpeg, if it should be FOSS and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

> MPEG Streamclip is a powerful free video converter, player, editor for
>   Mac and Windows.

http://www.squared5.com/