# Batch-convert iphone MOV videos to a Windows-friendly format?

Tags: video, batch, video-conversion, quicktime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch convert videos from MPG to AVI](https://superuser.com/questions/193379/batch-convert-videos-from-mpg-to-avi)

My iPhone records videos in Apple's MOV format. I do all my media management on a PC where MOV is cumbersome. I would like to convert all my existing MOV files to a Windows-friendly format.

- **Should be a one-click tool;** I want to do this for *all* the video files, and it's not feasible to load each individual file into a video-editing program and manually "save as" another format. I want to enqueue lots of files at once and then come back a day later and have the target files.
- **Should be lossless,** or at least as lossless as possible.
- **Target format** can be AVI, MP4, or anything similarly **compatible.**

Comment: Isn't the file from the iPhone already a MP4 container (with a mov extension) with MPEG-4 AVC video? Since I could not find reliable information, you should check what kind of container and audio/video format your source files have, e.g. unsing http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/ (assuming you use Windows). Without this information it is hard to tell if lossless conversion is possible and to recommend the best conversion settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows, without appropriate codec libraries, doesn't support *anything* useful apart from MPEG-1 and MPEG-2 video. If you were to convert your iPhone videos to that format, you'd lose a lot of quality and the files would be huge.

If you install codec libraries like [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/), then Windows should be able to play almost any video on its own. This would mean that you don't have to re-convert your h.264 iPhone videos – because re-encoding is never good.

If the MOV container is what irks you (or, Windows), then you could use [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) to wrap it to an MP4 container. I don't think this will heavily increase compatibility, but it's worth a shot. Also, it won't re-encode the video and audio bitstreams, it'll just change the container format. It's rather easy to wrap this is in a batch file for all videos, I guess.

```
mp4box -add input.mov -new output.mp4
```

Again, I don't see a lot of value in re-encoding videos to an old codec just so Windows supports it out of the box. That's like opening your door with a sledge hammer just because you forgot to install a doorknob.

Comment: +1 for remuxing not transcoding.

Comment: You're right, I didn't intend to do _reencoding_ but I wasn't clear on the terms or possibilities. What I want is to have anything that isn't MOV so that my non-Apple apps can play them.

Answer (score 1):

Use Total video Converter
 http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Encoders-Converter-DIVX-Related/Total-Video-Converter.shtml

Comment: Which format do you recommend the OP should convert his videos to? Which video codec? What settings should they choose so as not to lose quality?

Comment: use mkv format and h.264 as codec.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/193402/9350) solves it:

> SUPER © (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) can do it. One of its features is multiple batch file processing by simple file drag and drop, and it's freeware.