# Convert a video with command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, video-conversion

How can I convert a video file from ".avi" to ".mpeg" with the command prompt? I use Windows 10.

Comment: You can use any number of command prompt base utilities to do this, but the command prompt by itself, does not have this functionality.  Software recommendations are specifically out of scope here at Superuser

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/193379/batch-convert-videos-from-mpg-to-avi?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no built-in utility** within the Windows command prompt for converting videos from one format to another. You will have to download a **third-party** video conversion utility for this.

For example, *VLC Media Player* provides support for video format conversion. To use *VLC* for your purpose, see [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+a+video+from+avi+to+mpeg+in+vlc+command+line&sourceid=opera) and the [*VLC* Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/).

An example command may be perhaps this:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\vlc.exe" --no-repeat --no-loop -vvv "C:\Movies\my_video.avi" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst="C:\my_video_output.mpg"}
```

Various other programs can also be used.